Is this outfit of Lisa Simpson's from an official source or fan-made?
I came across this image on the Internet, and thought Lisa looked really adorable in this outfit, but I am not sure which episode it comes from, or if it comes from an episode at all. I tried a reverse search, but with no luck. Could anyone please tell me whether this comes from an official source or is fan-made; and if it is official, which episode or comic issue it is from?


This outfit is from the episode "Father Knows Worst" (S20E18):

Having burned his tongue and rendered it extra-sensitive to taste Homer samples the bland food at the school cafeteria where he also sees for himself that Bart is a hopeless scholar and Lisa a social outcast. He decides to be a good father by teaching Lisa how to be a popular socialite and helping Bart build a model of Westminster Abbey for his class project. Both ventures fail,though at least it has helped the kids find their own level and there are compensations for him in the sauna that Marge has recently discovered in the basement.


